# Mathematical calculation

Tags: matrices, mathematical-modeling, statistical-mechanics

I encountered during my reading to ridge regression that

$$(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TX = I-\lambda(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}$$

What mathematical manipulation has been done here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aweygan Truly speaking, here is not a new answer ; but I want to stress that the issue (or its answer) could be made even simpler because the special form $X^TX$ **plays no rôle**.

More precisely, let us reformulate the question under the form :

Show that, for a $n \times n$ matrix A, we have :

$$(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A = I-\lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}$$

Answer : This relationship is equivalent to the equation obtained by pre-multiplying both sides by $(A+\lambda I)$ (assumed invertible), i.e., :

$$A=A$$

which is evidently true.

Comment: @ Aweygan, @JeanMarie, thanks ever so much guys for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's true if $-\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $X^TX$:

\begin{align*}
(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TX+\lambda(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}&=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TX+(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}\cdot\lambda I\\
&=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}(X^TX+\lambda I) \\
&=I. 
\end{align*}
Then subtracting $\lambda(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}$ from both sides, we obtain the result.

As far as finding a  "mathematical manipulation" for this goes, I do not think there is one.  However, it is similar to the relation which holds for real numbers $x\neq-\lambda$:
$$\frac{x}{x+\lambda}=1-\frac{\lambda}{x+\lambda}. $$

Comment: Could you please make it more clear , I am confused

Comment: I'll edit and expand

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: @ Aweygan, I am not sure about the following , 1- why did you add something to the left hand side to the original formula.  2- where does the second line of the right hand side of your solution comes from

Comment: 1- This was to show that the equation was valid. I moved everything except for $I$ in the equation to one side, and tried to show that it equals $I$.
2-I factored out $(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}$.

Comment: @  Aweygan  , many thanks the first one becomes very clear , but the second not yet